# How to change FontWeigth of Window Title in Mahapps.MetroWindow

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I can not change Font Weight in MetroWindow Title. How can i do this?
I can set FontWeihgt in MetroWindow Attributes, but it affect all controls in my XAML code...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the `TitleTemplate` property of the `MetroWindow`.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="8 -1 8 0"
                   FontWeight="Light"
                   FontSize="{DynamicResource WindowTitleFontSize}"
                   FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```

Or with upper case for the title:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Converter={Converters:ToUpperConverter}}"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="8 -1 8 0"
                   FontWeight="Light"
                   FontSize="{DynamicResource WindowTitleFontSize}"
                   FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answer of @punker76, in ver. 2.x resources are renamed, so the example would be

```
<mah:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                 TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="8 -1 8 0"
                 FontWeight="Normal"
                 FontSize="{DynamicResource MahApps.Font.Size.Window.Title}"
                 FontFamily="{DynamicResource MahApps.Fonts.Family.Window.Title}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</mah:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```